# Python Import No Module Named error

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip

I pip installed pdfminer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/20140328 on ubuntu 13.10
and that successfully installed into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pdfminer

when I try to run the example code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice


if __name__=='__main__':
    # Open a PDF file.
    fp = open('MyPDF.pdf', 'rb')
```

I keep getting

```
ImportError: No module named pdfparser
```

I have verified that pdfparser exists and there is a `__init__.py` file in the pdfminer folder. I have tried recreating the `__init__.py` file. I have also tried runing `chmod -R 777 pdfminer` but that doesn't fix it either.

I have run `env` but there is no `PYTHONPATH` there is that a problem?
I have also tried installing PDFMiner into a virtualenv but that doesn't work either.
I noticed that PDFMiner requires root permissions to install is that the problem?

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the right python to execute your script? In your case, it should be /usr/local/bin/python I guess.

Comment: How about `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`? Do you have your `pdfminer` there?

Comment: I am just using `$python myscript.py` to execute the script. I just tried adding `#!/usr/local/bin/python` to the top of the file no difference/

Comment: @KillerSnail try `$/usr/local/bin/python myscript.py`, add #! at the top of script would only tell shell to use the specified binary to execute the script if you run the script with `$ ./myscript.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
from pdfminer import pdfparser
```

or

```
import pdfminer.pdfparser
```

?

Comment: I get `ImportError: cannot import name pdfparser` and `ImportError: No module named pdfparser` respectively

Comment: Hmmm try downloading the folder and running sudo python setup.py install

Comment: Misrab's answers works for me. As he says, try to reinstall the package. Maybe you forgot the "sudo" ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the code from a file called pdfminer.py?

This was causing the error in my case. Python was trying to import the module from the file of the same name.